# Cast passed arg to string

Tags: python, casting, arguments, string-formatting

Newbie at Python and maybe I'm not stating the question right, but how do I cast a passed arg to string in python?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Python Wrapper to Call XMLRPC service

import xmlrpclib
import sys  

# Set the Server
servAddr = "http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc.server.php"

# Start the Client
client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(servAddr)

for arg in sys.argv:
    id = str(arg)
    print client.service.setId(id) # Throws long error
    # print client.service.setId('123') # Hard coded works
    #print arg # prints the id passed
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "long error"? `str(arg)` is the correct way to turn arg into a string.

Comment: sorry for not posting the error, it's long and I didn't want to spend the time taking out all the real script name, etc... Thanks for you efforts though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The values from `sys.argv` already are strings. I think the problem is that you are passing sys.argv[0] which is the script name. Try this:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print client.service.setId(arg)
```

Comment: hmm one question, in the for loop it doesn't print the script name at all, just the id. But this does make sense to me coming from PHP as this happens in that language as well. Thanks again

Comment: @Phill Pafford: The `[1:]` is the syntax for slicing. It gives you a new list with all the elements except the first one. Then you iterate over the new list.

Answer (score 1):

Your args in sys.argv should already be strings. What makes you think you need to cast it o a string?

Don't you think you should probably post the error?

But anyway, you're doing it wrong anyway. The first argument to argv is the name of the script. You probably want

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    id = str(arg)
    print client.service.setId(id)
```

Also, you should have just put a print statement in the loop to see exactly what was being passed to setId().

Comment: In my example I do show that I printed out the args in a for loop, just seems the the script name is in the index first.

Comment: You're printing out the args much after your exception is being thrown. You should put it as the first thing in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want an integer. Each `arg` that gets passed in is *already* a string so there would be no reason to cast it as you are doing. Try `int(arg)` instead.

Comment: Sorry if you look at my commented out examples you will see that I'm passing in a string, which has been tested and works. Thanks for the efforts